# Can appium set airplane mode on/off on real device/simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, appium, airplane-mode

Does anyone know how to set airplane mode on/off on real device/simulator on Appium for iOS?

Comment: Signatures in questions are considered noise. Please avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. iOS won't allow it.

Comment: I have been trying to use swipe to access control center to do it that way, but having no joy:
  driver.swipe(halfWidth, screenHeight, halfWidth, screenHeight-300, 500);